# extracting values from html table using beautifulsoup4 (2nd row onwards, 1st and 6th column)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-tableextract

I am new to python and need some guidance on extracting values from specific cells from a HTML table.

The URL that I am working on can be found [here](http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/da/DailySettlement.xsl&url=/da/DailySettlement/V1/DSReport/ProductCode/C/FOI/FUT/EXCHANGE/XCBT/Underlying/C/ProductId/300?tradeDate=12/17/2013&currentTime=1387381389804)

I am looking to get the first 5 values only in the Month and Settlement columns and subsequently display them as:

```
"MAR 14:426'6"
```

Problem that I am facing is:

1. How do I get the loop to start from the 3rd "TR" in the table
2. How to get only values for td[0] and td[6].
3. How to restrict the loop to only retrieve values for 5 rows

This is the code that I am working on:

```
tableData = soup1.find("table", id="DailySettlementTable")
for rows in tableData.findAll('tr'):
    month = rows.find('td')
    print month
```

Thank you and appreciate any form of guidance!

Comment: It may be cleaner and easier to extract *all* data into a list of lists, and *then* get the fields you want. It's not as performant, of course, but you probably don't need to worry about that just yet, especially since you're new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice).

Here's a modified snippet for your code:

```
table = soup.find('table', id='DailySettlementTable')

# The slice notation below, [2:7], says to take the third (index 2)
# to the eighth (index 7) values from the rows we get.
for rows in table.find_all('tr')[2:7]:
    cells = rows.find_all('td')
    month = cells[0]
    settle = cells[6]

    print month.string + ':' + settle.string
```